# Set <UITouch>? does not have a member named Generator

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, xcode7

I find it hard to fix this error please who can help me
xcode 7 beta 2

> Set UITouch ? does not have a member named Generator

```
      override func touchesCancelled(touches: Set<UITouch>?, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
        for obj in touches {
            if let touch = obj as? UITouch {
                let view = self.touchToView[touch]

                self.handleControl(view, controlEvent: .TouchCancel)

                self.touchToView[touch] = nil
            }
        }

    }
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AXXzb.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to unwrap the optional - try

```
for obj in touches! {
   // code here
}
```

Comment: I have another small mistake ... I can upload it here or simply register a new question??

Comment: Probably best to open a new question. Protip - you can paste your whole code in spoilers into the question box to put the code inline :)